# How can I customize the mini-Controller from Cast Companion Library?

Tags: android, chromecast, castcompanionlibrary

I would like to customize the mini controller that sits at the bottom of the screen but I am not exactly sure how to replace or customize that without modifying Cast Companion Library (CCL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy over mini_controller.xml layout file from CCL into your own project (keep the name) and modify the layout as you see fit. If you want something more, you would need to implement IMiniController yourself.

Comment: I see now. Thanks for your reply to this and my other question. Now I see that I just need to create a composite views that implements IMiniController and can specify that when I call VideoCastManager.addMiniController(...) thanks